# Is using Image.onload the only way to draw a file to canvas?

Tags: canvas, firefox-addon

I am allowing user to browse for file. And then I do `var img = new Image` and then load image to here than in the onload part of the image I draw it to the canvas. Is this the only way or is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image`s loads are async and that is the way things are. So it is either `onload` or `addEventListener("load", ...)`.

You could potentially play with the underlying XPCOM stuff, but I wouldn't call that "straight-forward". I'm not even sure enough of XPCOM is exposed to JS to do proper sync loads anyway...
And IIRC the low-level XPCOM stuff is async at its core and just mimics sync-ness by explicitly blocking while waiting for async calls to return.

You could "hide" the async-ness a bit by using `Task.jsm` and Promises, but things will be still async, of course, just the source code would *look* "sync-y".

You could sync-decode the image yourself and `ctx.createImageData()`/`ctx.getImageData`, but that is more or less the opposite of "straight-forward".

So in conclusion: Just use the standard async API.

Comment: Thanks man that ctx method was what I was thinking, but i didn't know Image was async, I prefer that way then thanks.